# How can I compile 64 bit Applications using g++?

Tags: c++, g++

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x = 5;

    int* ptr = &x;

    std::cout << ptr << "\n";
}
```

I'm trying to compile to 64bit Application
with the command

> g++ -m64 *.cpp

but the pointer is always gives me a 32-bit pointer(0x61fe14)
why it is not working
isn't it suppose to give me something like 0x000000C9128FF9B4
why its compiling it to 32-bit Application

Comment: `0x61fe14` and `0x00000061fe14` are the same thing.  If you want to make sure you are compiling in a 64 bit system, check the `sizeof` the pointer.  If it is `8`, you are in 64 bit system.

Comment: You don't get leading zeros unless you ask for them.

Comment: In both cases it gives me 8 with and without -m64

Comment: Then most likely you are on a 64 bit machine, so it compiles it to 64 bit by default.  Does it print `4` if you use `-m32`?

Comment: it gives me error but I tried what you said on visual studio it worked prints 4 for 32-bit and 8 for 64-bit thx